# light sensor brick - what is n pin?

Tags: pins, terminology

I'm using a light brick sensor, which has a 4 pin grove interface and a 3 pin 2.54mm pin interface.

Sorry for the dumb question, but in the groove interface pin, there is a 'n' pin I don't know the use for. I'm strongly assuming that 'n' pin means 'none' or 'nothing', because this pin is not referenced in the datasheet.

My question is, does this 'n' pin is a standard label, and what is the meaning of it.

Thank you for the replies.

**edit**

For clarity here is the hardware photo:

[image]

As Spehro Pefhany clarified, 'N' is for not connected.

If i have not provided the data sheet section is because the 'N' pin part is mentioned anywhere.

But for what i understand, and correct me if I am wrong, I can deduce that 'N' or 'NC' can be considered anytime as "Not connected".

Comment: **NC** means *Not Connected*, which is the closest in meaning to what you're assuming. But there's no way for us to know if you don't provide the sensor part number, datasheet or a picture. Could you please post some links so we can try and find out?

Comment: Hi, Ricardo, my question was about if 'n' was part of a standardized nomenclature like 'G' or 'v'. As it was not included into the datasheet i thougt it was not necessary to include it.  Thank you for your answer

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. The very least required is a good photo of the device, but even then it is not guaranteed that anyone can say anything about it. It must have come with a manual.

Comment: No, there is no such standardization. NC will usually mean either "not connected" or sometimes "do not connect" (though DNC might be used for the latter). If "N" has any kind of standardized meaning at all, it would be Neutral on the mains. You just have to read the documentation, and ask if it's not completely clear. Anyone can write whatever letters they like on there, and chances are the person who did that didn't spend much time thinking about it- they used single letters because they would fit more easily.

Comment: No, you cannot __assume__ that signals marked 'N' or 'NC' are not connected. In a.c. power wiring, 'N' means neutral. The letters marked on a board are just a hint...always verify the connections if you value your hardware and your life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is like [this one](http://imall.iteadstudio.com/im120710017.html), the pinout looks like this:

[image]

And the schematic looks like this:

[image]

So the "N" connection on the "Grove" connector is just an "NC" (not connected).

It's not a dumb question at all, the documentation is pretty sketchy.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the same. Than you for your effort!